# How to get ad_id in Facebook Ads?

Tags: facebook, ads, instagram-api, facebook-ads-api

I want to moderate Instagram ads, but I can not access the ad_id. I have done the "http delete request" to enter the ad_id value but I get an error. How can i get the ad_id in facebook ads api?

DELETE REQUEST URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/<ID_HASH_STRING>
```

BODY PARAMETERS:

```
{
    "ad_id":"number12321435",
    "access_token":"xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "appsecret_proof":"xxxxxxxxx"
}
```

RESPONSE:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Param ad_id must be a valid Adgroup ID",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "CAwgnuVEWYl"
  }
}
```

DOCS:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/instagramads/ad_creative/v2.9 (under "Post Moderation").

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem!

You must follow this order to get ad_id and remove comment successfully;

1. `act_id/ads`   // this end-point gives you id = ad_id which is required to delete a comment or create a comment.If you want to get comments belongs to this ad_id follow order. Assume that id value is '011011011'
2. `ad_id/adcreatives` // if you use this endpoint with  fileds=effective_instagram_story_id you'll get Ad Creative's Feeds with this feed id you'll get comments
3. `effective_instagram_story_id/comments` // gives you latest comments pick a comment's id
4. `aWdfY29tbWVudDoxNz**********?ad_id=011011011` // send delete request and then it's working! As you can see that we used '011011011' id in order to delete this comment at first section.

Answer (score -1):

You want to moderate an Instagram ad, but you do not have the ad id. So what do you have? Let's assume you should have your ad account id. In that case, you can use:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/act_/ads?fields=name

You can see all the ads of the ad account. Based on the name, hopefully, you can tell which ad you are talking about. Or you can use some other fields to find your ad. But no matter what, you need to know your ad, before you can moderate an ad.